Perform OSC 52 copying from a tmux key-bound command
I'm connecting from my local Windows machine to a remote Linux machine, in which I run Byobu, which uses tmux. I have a command bound to a key like this:
unbind-key p
bind-key p run '/home/ramrachum/bin/_polina_trek_echo.sh'

I want that _polina_trek_echo.sh script to copy a piece of generated text into the clipboard of the local Windows machine. A good way to do it with with OSC 52, like piping the output into this script I wrote that I call sclip:
#!/usr/bin/env python
import base64
import sys

message = sys.stdin.read()    
encoded_message = base64.b64encode(message.encode()).decode()
print(f'\033]52;;{encoded_message}\007', end='', file=sys.stderr)

Very demure, very mindful. However, when you pipe text into that script inside a script that's bound using bind-key, that text does not end up in the clipboard. I assume this is because Byobu/tmux shows the script's output in a less window, causing the OSC 52 magic to not take effect.
Is there a solution for this, or an alternative way for the script bound by bind-key to copy text into the local Windows machine's clipboard?

TMUX_PANE_PID="$(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_pid}')"
TMUX_PANE_STDERR="/proc/${TMUX_PANE_PID}/fd/2"
echo "Your text" | sclip 2> "$TMUX_PANE_STDERR"

